# Does "I’m so happy because my mother gives me a present" sound strange?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, tense

See this dialog:

> A: Hello ___.
>
> B: Oh hi ____.
>
> A: I’m so happy because my mother gives me a present.
>
> B: Oh what is it?
>
> A: It is a new pencil case.
>
> B:Great!

I would say this context is talking about a specific thing - a thing that happened for now, not a repetitive thing.

So, in that respect, I would say "*I’m so happy because my mother gives me a present*" sentence sounds very wrong to me.

I would think the best response should be "*I’m so happy because my mother gave me a present*" or "*I’m so happy because my mother has just given me a present*". because the "**action of giving a present**" finished in the past.

"*I’m so happy because my mother gives me a present*" sounds like "*I’m happy whenever my mother gives me a present*" (a repeated action)

**Am I right?**

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about the event happened in the past and ends in your happiness.

To use this sentence is the best way to express the situation.

> I’m so happy because my mother gave me a present"

or

> "I’m so happy because my mother has just given me a present".